# Should the empty set be called "half-open"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, terminology

Empty set is both open and closed in any metric space (also in any topological space). Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with usual metric. In this metric space, should we say that the empty set is *half open*?

Comment: What does 'half open' mean?

Comment: What is a "half open" set?  I know what a half-open interval is, and a half-open interval is neither open nor closed.  But as for a "half open set" in a metric space, I know of no such concept. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The empty set is clopen, is that what you mean?

Comment: Because the full set is not oposed (distinctly pronounce *one* p).

Comment: Consider R with usual metric. In this metric space, should we say that the empty set is half open?

Answer (score 2):

A set that is both open and closed is (sometimes) called *clopen*.  The empty set is a clopen set in any metric space and indeed in any topological space. (All metric spaces are topological.)

As far as I know, "half-open" is not meaningful in general metric spaces.  For example, there is no such thing as a half-open subset of $\Bbb R^2$.  "Half-open" is meaningful in totally ordered spaces, which are spaces that admit a transitive and total $\lt$ relation. One example is the real line $\Bbb R$.  In such a space, "half-open" refers a sets of the form $$[a,b) = \{x \mid a \le x \lt b \}$$ or $$(a,b] = \{x \mid a \lt x \le b\}$$ for some $a,b \in X$.

Note that such spaces are not, in general, metric spaces.

Comment: Dear MJD, what is half open set in general metric space..?

Comment: As far as I know, "half-open" is not meaningful in general metric spaces.

Comment: i think your answer is correct... but still i am really confused with empty set...!!

Comment: empty set= (1,0)        empty set= (1,0]      empty set= [1,0)     empty set= [1,0].... They are inervals in R.

Comment: So what's your point?

Comment: there is no points...  so How i apply the definition of open set and closed set on the empty set..?